# Show that a sequence involving $\sqrt2$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Show that the  sequence

$$\sqrt2, \sqrt{2\sqrt{2}},\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}} ,\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}}},...$$

converges and find the limit

Comment: It's increasing and bounded, so it converges and can be solved by $x = \sqrt {2x}$

Comment: This has been answered before, sorry can't find it. First term is $2^{1/2}$. Second term is $2^{1/2+1/4}$. Next term is $2^{1/2+1/4+1/8}$. And so on. Note that the exponents form a geometric series sum $1$.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence is given by $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2a_n}$. Here is a roadmap:

- Prove that $a_n < 2$.
- Prove that $a_{n+1} > a_n$.
- Conclude that $(a_n)$ converges.
- If $L=\lim a_n$, then $L=\sqrt{2L}$.

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$x_n=2^{1-2^{-n}}\quad n=1,2,\ldots$$
Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=2$.

Comment: I like this solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that the sequence is increasing and use the fact that $\sqrt2\leq2$ to show $x_n\leq2$ for all $n$. This shows convergence, say to $x$. Then you have $\sqrt{2x}=x$ (why?) and you can solve this for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Define a sequence $(u_n)_{n \ge 0}$ by $u_0 = 1$ and $u_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 u_n}$.

We can show recursively that $u_n \le u_{n+1} \le 2$. So $(u_n)_{n \ge 0}$ converges. Let $l$ be the limit, we have that $l = \sqrt{2l}$, so $l = 2$.

Alternatively, define $v_n = \log_2(u_n)$. We have $v_0 = 0$ and $v_{n+1} = \frac{1+v_n}{2}$, so we can show $v_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{2^k} \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 1$.